# Getting wrong ID

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, id

I have a page template with a custom query. The query displays posts from a post type. I want to display the ID's of the queried posts, but when I use this...

```
<?php $id = the_ID(); ?>
```

All I get is the page ID. Can anyone give me some tips?

Page Code...

```
<?php
 if ( have_properties() ) {

   $thumbnail_dimentions = WPP_F::get_image_dimensions($wpp_query['thumbnail_size']);

?>
  <?php foreach ( returned_properties('load_gallery=false') as $property) {  ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <?php property_overview_image(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-8">
               <!--Building Title-->
                  <h3><a <?php echo $in_new_window; ?> href="<?php echo $property['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $property['post_title']; ?></a>
                    <?php if( !empty( $property['is_child'] ) ): ?>
                        of <a <?php echo $in_new_window; ?> href='<?php echo $property['parent_link']; ?>'><?php echo $property['parent_title']; ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?></h3>
                       <!--Building Title-->

                         <p><?php if( !empty( $property['address'] ) ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $property['permalink']; ?>#property_map"><?php echo $property['address']; ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?></p>


                <p>  <?php if( !empty( $property['phone_number'] ) ): ?>
                <?php echo $property['phone_number']; ?>
            <?php endif; ?></p>

               <p> <?php if( !empty( $property['fax_number'] ) ): ?>
               <?php echo $property['fax_number']; ?>
            <?php endif; ?></p>


           <p> <?php if( !empty( $property['price'] ) ): ?>
               <?php echo $property['price']; ?>
            <?php endif; ?></p>

<?php $id = the_ID(); ?>


         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUnits<?php
echo the_ID(); ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseUnits<?php
echo the_ID(); ?>">
 View Unit Details <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseUnits<?php
echo the_ID(); ?>">
  <div class="well">
  <!--Building Unit Info-->
            <?php if( $show_children && !empty( $property['children'] ) ): ?>
                <div class="wpd_floorplans_title"><?php echo $child_properties_title; ?></div>
                <table class="wpp_overview_child_properties_table">
                    <?php foreach($property['children'] as $child): ?>
                    <tr class="property_child_row">
                        <th class="property_child_title"><a href="<?php echo $child['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $child['post_title']; ?></a></th>
                        <td class="property_child_price"><?php echo isset( $child['price'] ) ? $child['price'] : ''; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </table>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                 <!--Building Unit Info-->
  </div>
</div>         
            <?php if(!empty($wpp_query['detail_button'])) : ?>
           <a <?php echo $in_new_window; ?> class="button" href="<?php echo $property['permalink']; ?>"><?php echo $wpp_query['detail_button'] ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><?php // .col6 ?>

    </div><?php // .row ?>


    <?php } /** end of the propertyloop. */ ?>


<?php } else {  ?>
   <p><?php echo sprintf(__('Sorry, no properties found - try expanding your search, or <a href="%s">view all</a>.','wpp'), site_url().'/'.$wp_properties['configuration']['base_slug']); ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is that in the loop? I think you need to show more of your code.

Comment: No, it is not in the standard loop :/ I'm using WP Properties template. I will paste my code.

Comment: Your code does not seem complete, and it does seem that the code you have posted is not really relevant. How does your query look like and how is your loop constructed, how do you query and display the posts. Also, only post the relevant code. It makes it easier to read and it is less frustrating to work through

Comment: This is the template provided by wp properties. I've only made some layout modifications. This template is called into a standard page via a shortcode. If it's too complex for here, I'll try to seek out a developer's help. I did think it would be too hard.